# EXM Open rate is not updated right away

Tags: exm

I am working in EXM, I have created an Automated Email campaign and sent mail by using the form action. After opening the mail, I checked the EXM dashboard, but it still shows an open rate as 0.so is there any way to update the open rate immediately?

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons for the open or click rate not updating on the EXM dashboard.
But before checking the logs and config settings, make sure you've checked the below points:

1. Check if you've configured the default settings correctly, mainly the base URL parameter. This URL should be correct and should be reachable from the machine you're opening the emails. Check this link https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/edit-the-exm-default-settings.html
2. Go to Email root in the content editor (/Sitecore/content/Email) and look for this field **Track Message Open** and confirm this should be checked.
   [image]
3. EXM sends an IMG pixel with each email, which is responsible for tracking the opening of an email. This img tag is present at the end of the email (if you see the HTML source code of the email), something like this:

   <img height=3D"1" width=3D"1" border=3D"0" style=3D"border-color: transparent;" src=3D"https://somedomain.com/sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/RegisterEmailOpened.ashx?ec_eq=3DkRYrGM5CERgrLsiuJXSZKP0aZchMDm7E4MnZLnTXwPKnAKAb3iNP4gBPbUUkKsfBlNdK4SmTkm2hfAs2bbg23aVWCUHaAVhZa41n%2bXlJ6E96JHQtOmewSJr4Oja0Ph0aDrnNLc34pDduPIStgMtgjoOuLX%2fvkqS4ixd95eXk%2b7UTkFKsWodkftuZaaCBfy84zVEI%2fQdmWp%2faKOAxGjCLSg%3d%3d" alt=3D"" />

So, make sure this tag loads correctly. Take the src URL and check if this URL is reachable.